# Codeigniter set_template() creates two thead tag

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter to help me create a table from mySQL database, but the  set_template() will create two thead tags for me. I don't know why this happens. And here is what I got after codeigniter create the table:

```
<table id = "guestList" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
<thead>
<thead style="background: #E3EBEE; font-size: 15px;color: #1C75BC;">
<th style="padding: 10px;">Order#</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Qty</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Customer</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Order Date</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Ticket Type</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Price</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Delivery Method</th>
<th style="padding: 10px;">Option</th>
</thead>
</thead>
```

This is the code that create the table:

```
<?php
                            $tmpl = array (
                                'table_open'          => '<table id = "guestList" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">',

                                'heading_row_start'   => '<thead style="background: #E3EBEE; font-size: 15px;color: #1C75BC;">',
                                'heading_row_end'     => '</thead>',
                                'heading_cell_start'  => '<th style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',

                                'row_start'           => '<tr>',
                                'row_end'             => '</tr>',
                                'cell_start'          => '<td style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'cell_end'            => '</td>',

                                'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
                                'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
                                'cell_alt_start'      => '<td style="padding: 10px;">',
                                'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',

                                'table_close'         => '</table>'
                            );
                            $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
                            $this->table->set_heading('Order#', 'Qty' , 'Customer', 'Order Date', 'Ticket Type', 'Price', 'Delivery Method');
                            echo $this->table->generate($record);
?>
```

Comment: Heading_row_start has to be <tr>. The end </tr>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [CodeIgniter table documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html?highlight=table), the `heading_row_start` is what the specific item the row is going to start with.  This is different from the open and close tags which you are defining in those items, which should be done as part of `thead_open` and `thead_close`.

The example from the documentation is as follows:

```
$template = array(
        'table_open'            => '<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">',

        'thead_open'            => '<thead>',
        'thead_close'           => '</thead>',

        'heading_row_start'     => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end'       => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start'    => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end'      => '</th>',

        'tbody_open'            => '<tbody>',
        'tbody_close'           => '</tbody>',

        'row_start'             => '<tr>',
        'row_end'               => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'            => '<td>',
        'cell_end'              => '</td>',

        'row_alt_start'         => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end'           => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start'        => '<td>',
        'cell_alt_end'          => '</td>',

        'table_close'           => '</table>'
);
```

So you'd need to replace your

```
'heading_row_start'   => '<thead style="background: #E3EBEE; font-size: 15px;color: #1C75BC;">',
'heading_row_end'     => '</thead>',
```

lines with :

```
'thead_open'   => '<thead style="background: #E3EBEE; font-size: 15px;color: #1C75BC;">',
'thead_close'     => '</thead>',
```

Comment: I'm having another question. As you can see I have columns like `Qty` and `Price`. Is that possible to use the template to create the entire column of table cell with a class name? For example`<tr class="qty"></tr>` for the `Qty` column